# Where to download this version of adventureworks database

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

Hi all, I started studying SQL Server from this book [SQL Server 2008
Transact-SQL Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599802).

My problem is I can't get this file `AdventureWorks2008.msi`.

> A majority of the examples in this book use the AdventureWorks
>   database (SQL Server 2008 OLTP version), which can be downloaded
>   online from the CodePlex site (www.codeplex.com), under the “Microsoft
>   SQL Server Product Samples: Database” project. Look for the file named
>   AdventureWorks2008.msi

When I searched I get [this](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10870633/138938

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to download AdventureWorks2008.msi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870537/where-to-download-adventureworks2008-msi)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL 2008 AdventureWorks download is available [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/37109) - it's an exe, give that a try :)

Answer (score 1):

the link "AdaTheDev posted is for SQL Server 2008R2.

If you want the SQL Server 2008 (there are differences on some table's structures), try [this](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/37109) link

I'm posting this because I had problems testing code built to the regular DB while I had the R2 installed

Answer (score 1):

The book is outdated and refers to a file that is no longer available for public download. See this answer to get the database downloaded and installed so that you can work through the examples in the book:

[Where to download AdventureWorks2008.msi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10870537/138938)