# Where to download AdventureWorks2008.msi?

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

I'd like to install **AdventureWorks2008** (I just install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express).

Each time I download the recommended version from CodePlex, all I get is a `AdventureWorks2008.mdf` file. Not only I cannot attach the file from SQL Server Management Studio, but I cannot copy/paste the file directly into the the database.

I've read in several places that I need to use `AdventureWorks2008.msi`, but I cannot find where to download it.

I just cannot figure out how to install AdventureWorks2008

Thanks for helping

Comment: What happens when you try to attach the file in SSMS? Do you get an error?

Comment: I tried that SQL command and also manual attaching of the mdf file. Both methods cause the same error. My agony is at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060441/cannot-install-adventureworks-2012-database-operating-system-error-5-access-i

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't an .msi file for adventureworks, even though you'll find it mentioned in outdated documentation and books. You aren't alone in finding this confusing -- it seems the web site, files and steps Microsoft provides for installing these databases changes every time I need to install them.

You need to create the database and attach the .mdf file, which is the "data file" referred to in the instructions. *(.mdf = primary data file, .ldf = log file, .ndf = secondary data file)*

In order to attach the file, you need to make sure you carefully follow the steps here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3735.sql-server-samples-readme-en-us.aspx#Readme_for_Adventure_Works_Sample_Databases

Instructions for 2008R2:

> To install AdventureWorks2008R2 OLTP database
>
> 1. Download the AdventureWorks2008R2 Data File.
> 2. From File Download, click Save and browse to a location on your local
>      server.
> 3. From SQL Server Management Studio, execute the following code:
>
> Case-insensitive Database

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 
ON (FILENAME = '{drive}:\{file path}\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf') 
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

> As an alternative to step 3, you can attach the database using the SQL
>   Server Management Studio user interface. For more detailed
>   information, see [Attach a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).
>
> Note: You must remove the log file from the list of files to attach.
>   This will cause the operation to rebuild the log.

**Headache saving tip from Aaron Bertrand:**

> You should place the mdf file in your normal data folder - SQL Server
>   will already have the proper permissions. You can get this path using

`SELECT TOP (1) physical_name FROM master.sys.database_files;`

Comment: By "AdventureWorks2008R2 Data File", you mean the one that has .mdf extension? If that's the case, I have already downloaded it. But I don't see any "Licence Agreement". The only file I get is the "AdventureWorks2008R2.mdf"

Comment: Yes, the data file is the .mdf. I just copied Microsoft's instructions from the site, so if there isn't a license agreement, just skip that step.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the eula acceptance step. I also added a legend for the sql server file extensions.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: "Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 3
Unable to open the physical file "C:\AdventureWorks2008OLTP\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"."

Comment: See if either of these links help you: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/539703/access-denied-attaching-a-database-when-permissions-are-inherited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330439/access-is-denied-when-attaching-a-database

Comment: @Richard77 you should place the mdf file in your normal data folder - SQL Server will already have the proper permissions. You can get this path using `SELECT TOP (1) physical_name FROM master.sys.database_files;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand: do you mind if I include your comment in my answer? (attributed, of course!)

Comment: @HeadofCatering not a problem.

Comment: I tried that SQL command and also manual attaching of the mdf file. Both methods cause the same error. My agony is at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060441/cannot-install-adventureworks-2012-database-operating-system-error-5-access-i

Comment: Did you try what Steve and Aaron suggest in the comments above? That resolved the issue for Richard77.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly paste that file into your database directory. For more information you can refer http://tryingmicrosoft.com/error-while-attaching-a-database-to-sql-server-2008-r2/.

Comment: You deserve a gold medal for posting that link. Thanks.