# Cannot install adventureworks 2012 database - Operating system error 5: Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to install AdventureWorks 2012 database in sql server 2012. I got the mdf file from this link - http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587

Here is the name of the file I downloaded - 
AdventureWorks2012_Database.zip

I am doing all this on a windows 7 64 bit.

I get the error below:

```
Attach database failed for Server 'SuperPC\SQL2012'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Unable to open the physical file "C:\Databases\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.2100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5120&LinkId=20476
```

Comment: Did you check if the file the zip file is Blocked. Right Click on the file there should be an option to unblock the file if its blocked.

Comment: @jcwrequests - I unzipped the files and then tried to install them onto sql server 2012.

Comment: Also check if the user that you're using to access the database has access to those files.

Comment: @Szymon - how do I do that ? Its an mdf and ldf file.

Comment: Go to where they are located and check the security in file properties.

Comment: Did you run an msi or did you unzipp the mdf file and try to attach too it?

Comment: Blocking will not stop you from unzipping the file but it will have the effect you described.

Comment: @jcwrequests - unzip the mdf and then Object explorer > MyDB > Databases > right-click > attach > add - I add my mdf file here.

Comment: @jcwrequests - how do I check if it is "blocked" ?

Comment: Before you unzip check the properties on the file.

Comment: @jcwrequests - okay. i am re-downloading the zips. How do I check if a zip file is "blocked" ? I don't understand what this block means.

Comment: http://dosysadminsdream.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/windows-2008-unblock-executable-button/ check this link to see what I mean about unblock.

Comment: okay, got it. saw the option. I am pasting the photo here.

Comment: @jcwrequests - no luck. I unblocked and unzipped it. Then, I tried to load it again. Fails with the same error.

Comment: Did you check if the mdf is blocked? Also chech the ownership on the mdf make sure that the server has appropriate ownership.

Comment: @jcwrequests - mdf is not blocked. How do I - make sure that the server has appropriate ownership ?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx this will give you info on ownership.

Comment: @zhongxiao37 - read my answer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The reason for the problem - Putting the database mdf and ldf files in a directory outside the "official" SQL server installation folder.

Solution -

http://tryingmicrosoft.com/error-while-attaching-a-database-to-sql-server-2008-r2/

Paste your .mdf file and ldf file in this directory - 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SS2012\MSSQL\DATA

Solutions that did NOT solve the problem -

1 - Unblocking the zipped files. Also checked that mdf and ldf files are
not blocked. (Steps - right click zip file > properties > unblock)

[image: Unblock]

2 - Run SSMS 2012 as administrator.

3 - Run SQL query of the form -

```
CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks 
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Comment: After I attach file in the default SQL server directory, I get the same access denied error when trying to access it with an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @PeterX - Did you try any of the solutions which did not work (DNW) for me or the answers given by other people ? See my 1st DNW point.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda - different strokes for different folks. Enjoy. If you like my answer, please upvote me. Thanks.

Comment: @Steam: was just mentioning it so that readers know that running as administrator **might** be a solution, even if it did not work for you

Answer (score 19):

Options

**1.**
Move .mdf and .ldf to SQLServer install directory \Data\ folder
(eg C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA)

**2.**
Run SQL Server Management Studio as Administrator

**3.**
Add rights to the SQL Server user to the directory you need access to. I wasn't sure which user was correct but managed to get it working by giving the "[PCNAME]\Users" account full access to the folder.

> *Steps*
>
> Right-Click folder. Select Properties. Select "Security" tab. Click
>   "Edit".  Select "Users ([PCNAME]\Users)" eg if the name of the pc was
>   mycomp then this would be "Users (mycomp\Users)"
>
> Click the "Allow" tickbox next to "Full control" under "Permissions
>   for Users"

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178536/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text-for-thi) for more details for options 1 & 2 ..

[CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178536/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text-for-thi)

Comment: Perhaps not a good idea to add just local users full control permissions to that directory. Rather, add `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` account to the permissions of the folder and grant full control.

Answer (score 14):

I've changed permissions and that worked for me:
security -> Advanced. Add 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER' and give full access, **disable inheritance**, add yourself for ease of troubleshooting. Do that on both .mdf and .ldf files.

Comment: I gave "User" full access to solve the problem. I guess limiting to just mssqlserver is better.

Comment: I had to do both current user and NT Server\MSSQLSERVER. I initially tried with just MSSQLSERVER but that didn't work. I then added my user with full permissions

Answer (score 7):

Error 5 - Access is denied - Comes from the old days of DOS.  Basically, it is an ACL - access control list error.

You can put databases anywhere you like as long as the SQL SERVER SERVICE account has access!

It doesn't matter who you are logged in as, it is the service account that needs access to the directory and files.

You do not need to run SSMS as an administrator.  I attached databases all the time without this step.

Comment: How did you do it ? Did you do what I mentioned in my answer ?

Comment: With Azure IaaS VM SQL Server 2012, I saw the same issue.  Adding the NT Service\MSSQLServer service account to security (FullControl) for the target drives solved my issue and I was able to set the ReadOnly option to False.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to move the `.mdf` file. Just right click the folder the database is in and change the security permissions. I gave *authenticated users* full control. Then I ran the TSQL script below to attach the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks 
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Adventureworks\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Adventureworks\AdventureWorks2012_Log.ldf') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

As you can see my database files are located in a folder called `Adventureworks`.

Comment: You are a genius! This was solution the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the log file, if you are creating the database for the first time by attaching, that might help you.

I was trying to create database by attaching and I kept getting a similar screenshot

[image]

Thanks to the article below I found and just had to remove the log, it was obvious but MS did not offer to not show by themselves for new databases. Very bad experience, not sure if its similar for SQL server licensed products.

http://exacthelp.blogspot.in/2012/12/unable-to-open-physical-file-operating.html

Answer (score 6):

Steps to attach AdventureWorks2012 database into your local MSSQL database:

**Solution 1:** If you have enough space in C:\ Drive in Windows and want to create the database in C:\ Drive

1. Place the AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf and AdventureWorks2012_log.ldf in the below location
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

2.Right click on 'Databases' in the object explorer and select 'Attach'

3.In the Attach Databases dialog box, Click on 'Add' button in the databases to attach: field.

4. Navigate to the MDF file location C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf and 
   click 'OK' in the bottom of the 'Attach Databases' dialog box.

5.Now the database 'AdventureWorks2012' is created in SQL Sever.

**Solution 2:** If you do not have enough space in C:\ Drive in Windows

1.Connect to your local server by selecting server name XXX\SQLEXPRESS and Authentication - 'Windows Authentication'

2.Right click on 'Databases' in the object explorer and select 'Attach'

3.In the Attach Databases dialog box, Click on 'Add' button in the databases to attach: field.

4. Navigate to the MDF file location for e.g. F:\AdventureWorks2012_Database\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf and click 'OK' in the bottom of the 'Attach Databases' dialog box.
5. This will generate the below error message:
   'An error occurred when attaching the database(s).  Click the hyperlink in the Message column for details.'
6. SOLUTION is :

   i) Right click on the AdventureWorks2012_Data folder, select Properties.

   ii) click on 'Security' tab

   iii) Select Users(xxx\Users) in the 'Group or user names:' section

   iv) Click on 'Edit' button

   v) Select Users(xxx\Users) in the 'Group or user names:' in the popup,

   vi) Check the 'Full control' check box in the 'Permissions for Users' section.

   vii) Click ok & ok.
7. Now back to SQLsevers's Attach Databases screen, Click on 'Add' button in the databases to attach: field.
8. Navigate to the MDF file location  e.g. F:\AdventureWorks2012_Database\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf and click 'OK' in the bottom of the 'Attach Databases' dialog box.
9. Now the database 'AdventureWorks2012' is created in SQL Sever.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, but for me there were actually two requirements for attaching a database *outside* the default folder:

1. I had to explicitly grant the current user (me) Full Access to the folder (despite already having implicit permissions)
2. I had to grant `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$INSTANCENAME` Full Access to the folder

I assume #1 isn't required if the process (SSMS) is elevated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Attach the database .
2. In the dialogue box, select the file location of the AdventureWorks.
3. Add the file.
4. Delete the log file, as the SQL server will create one later once the database is attached .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while trying to create new database with custom settings from ASP.NET MVS and I have lost few hours to solve it. 
Finally my solution was to get into folder options / seurity of my App_Data folder. Then I have add an account 'authenticated users' and gave him full control. 
And that was all. My application runs well ..

Answer (score 0):

### Giving the sql service account 'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER' "Full Control" of the database files

If you have access to the server files/folders you can try this solution that worked for me:

**SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2**

1. Right click the database (mdf/ldf) file or folder and select "Properties".
2. Select "Security" tab and click the "Edit" button.
3. Click the "Add" button.
4. Enter the object name to select as 'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER' and click "Check Names" button.
5. Select the MSSQLSERVER (RDN) and click the "OK" button twice.
6. Give this service account "Full control" to the file or folder.
7. Back in SSMS, right click the database and select "Properties".
8. Under "Options", scroll down to the "State" section and change "Database Read-Only" from "True" to "False".

Answer (score 0):

just add the current user to the security tab will full control and re-run atttach query

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading the Adventure works from this website

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/723031

Note when downloading an adventure works zip folder, ensure the file is appended with _data e.g  AdventureWorks2012_Data.zip as this file contains both the .mdf and .ldf files.

After it is downloaded, extract the folder contents to this url on your computer C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.***\MSSQL\DATA. In SQl server, go to the Object Explorer and Right click on the Databases to attach the database. In the Attach dialog box, you should select Adve********.mdf. Everything you should be fine from here.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Windows 7 Pro, SQL 2012

After using `DiskManager.msc`, I had to add `machine_name\SERVICE` with full control to both the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

My Laptop is Borris so:

1. Right click on file `name -> properties click SECURITY tab, then
   permissions -> add and then in check for names type in services.
2. To get back out hit ok, apply, ok, ok, ok, and ok.

Not sure why switching drive letters reset my permissions but it did on Windows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z04T2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for previous suggestions. You don't have to move the database files to the SQL server directory or delete the database log file. Instead you simply give the Full Control permission to both .MDF and .LDF files for Authenticated Users. By doing so I successfully attach both AdventureWorks2012 and AdventureWorksLT2012 sample databases in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Answer (score 0):

actually it's pretty easy. Just rename the files.
No need to move, add permissions run as whatever...

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by:

1. Attaching the file `AdventureWorks2012_Data`.

   1.1. Then the file `AdventureWorks2012_log` appears and does not exist.
2. Use the `Remove` button for eliminating the `.log` file.
3. Press `OK`.

Then the new database appears.

Answer (score -1):

iTS EASY, Just Stop the SQL Service, copy what you want or do the restore, and then start the service again... voiláaa
You cannot copy anything unless you stop the service. if the things you want to restore are on an active tree you cannot overwrite it, its locked, simple...

I know... thank me :)