# Access Denied when doing SQL Backup

Tags: c#, sql, security, permissions, database-backups

I am trying to use C# to backup selected databases in my WPF application. I think the code is fine, but when the backup runs, I get this error:

[image]

Since I received that error I tried to give the folder permissions to everyone through C# but I am still having the same issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
                DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(backupFolder);

                SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
                sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
                Directory.SetAccessControl(backupFolder, sec);

                List<string> dbNameList = GetDatabaseList();

                if (dbNameList != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand oCommand = null;
                    SqlConnection oConnection = null;
                    foreach (string dbName in dbNameList)
                    {
                        string command = @"BACKUP DATABASE " + dbName + " TO DISK='" + backupFolder + "'";   
                        oConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                        if (oConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            oConnection.Open();
                        oCommand = new SqlCommand(command, oConnection);
                        oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    oConnection.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the *Access Denied* is a bit misleading and is caused by the fact that 
`backupFolder` is a directory path as opposed to a file path pointing to a `.bak` file.

SQL Server is trying to open the *directory* for output which will fail in the observed fashion.

You need to pass a path containing the desired `.bak` output file.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what the problem was! I googled this error forever and no one mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [SQL Server Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286765/sql-server-operating-system-error-5-5access-is-denied) and [Cannot install adventureworks 2012 database - Operating system error 5: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060441/cannot-install-adventureworks-2012-database-operating-system-error-5-access-i)

These seem to be very similar and may have a possible solution to your problem.